# How to get selected ui element in applescript?

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to create script for application which doesn't have dictionary. How to get selected list item?

I need something like this

`tell application "System Events"
    tell process "process"
        get selected item of list 1 of splitter group 1 of window 1
    end tell
end tell`

_

`choose from list list 1...` fails with 1700 error (can't convert to string)

Comment: The question cannot be answered without knowing the target app, its version and exactly what you are going to accomplish. GUI scripting depends completely on the context.

Comment: @vidian song of god [download link](http://songofgod.ru/files/SongOfGod_1_2.zip).
I want to know witch verse is selected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the selected property of each of those particular elements (which are static text UI Elements) seems to be inaccessible.
Doing the following:

```
activate application "SongOfGod_1_2"

--(this line above is just to make sure
-- we don't miss anything by not having the app frontmost;
--for many commands it is unnecessary)

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "SongOfGod"
        properties of static text 2 of list 1 of splitter group 1 of group 1 of splitter group 1 of window 1
    end tell
end tell
```

returns:

```
{class:static text, minimum value:missing value, orientation:missing value, position:{595, 259}, accessibility description:"2. And the earth was without form, and void; and darkness was upon the face of the deep. And the Spirit of God moved upon the face of the waters.", role description:"text", focused:false, title:missing value, size:{1605, 18}, help:missing value, entire contents:{}, enabled:true, maximum value:missing value, role:"AXStaticText", value:missing value, subrole:missing value, selected:missing value, name:missing value, description:"2. And the earth was without form, and void; and darkness was upon the face of the deep. And the Spirit of God moved upon the face of the waters."}
```

You'll notice, if you scroll way out there, that the `selected` property returns `missing value`, which means you cannot determine if it is selected. I also tried `focused`, which doesn't work. Nor do `click` or `select` work. Trying to get the `selected` property of the list containing it also doesn't work.

You apparently cannot get what you want out of this app, I'm sorry to say.